# How can I use indexOf for string with "\"?

Tags: c#, string

I have a string with path for file like this for example: C:\Users\Ekaterina\Desktop\3DTrajektorienplaner\Planungstool\Dromedary.stl

Now I need only the name of the file: "Dromedary.stl".

I have tried  to find the last index of '\' and then delete everything before it, but I get an error, that '\' cannot be used.

I have also tried with remove function, but this path always has different length depending on the computer.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Use Path.GetFileName instead See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfilename?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: But if you ever *do* need backslash as a `char`, use `\\`

Comment: '\' is a skipping char, you need to skip it so the compiler understand thats its a char instead : int index = yourPath.IndexOf(@"\"); or int index = yourPath.IndexOf("\\");

Answer (score 4):

You can use Getfilename method to get the filename easily. [Read more on GetFileName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfilename?view=netframework-4.8)

```
string fileName = @"C:\mydir\myfile.ext";
string result;

result = Path.GetFileName(fileName);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to escape that character:

```
int index = yourPath.IndexOf("\\");
```

However, the best would be to use Path class